# SSH.NET Could not find a part of the path error

Tags: c#, ssh.net

I'm trying to use SSH.NET in C# code to access a database over SSH. I generate a RSA key pair and put the private key on an UNC shared drive. The pathname string looks like below. When I kick off the code trying to connect, I get a "Could not find a part of the path" error.

```
string privatekeypathname = @"\\server\My path\private_key.ppk";
```

I think using an UNC path is the issue. Is there any way to resolve the issue? Thanks.

Edit: I tried using a mapped drive. Same error. My Code looks like:

```
PrivateKeyFile key = new PrivateKeyFile(privatekeypathname, MyPassPhrase);
ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo(
    MySSHHost,
    MySSHPort,
    MySSHUser,
    new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod(MySSHUser, key));
sshClient = new SshClient(connectionInfo);
sshClient.Connect();
```

Note: I've tried a pathname that looks like: `@"C:\my folder\private_key.ppk"` and it works, so obviously the space in the string isn't the issue. Also, although I don't think permission is the issue, I've tried running the code as administrator and got the same error. I can manually access the shared drive using Windows Explorer. I don't know what else I can try to verify this end.

Comment: Is it possible that you missed the server of your share?

Comment: If the UNC is the problem, map a drive and try it that way.

Comment: Which version of SSH.Net are you using? The latest beta (2014.4.6-beta2) includes some changes to the code that opens private key files (requested permissions and share modes).

Comment: how are you using this string?

Comment: @Phil: tried the beta version of SSH.Net. Same deal.